# How to build a dataset and build_vocab in pytorch with txt files?

Tags: pytorch, torchtext

I have txt files for training and validation with letters inside for example

File_1:

hg jk lo ju jk lk

File 2:

sd sg gt gh qe

So I want to build a dataset with these files, (I have 5 labels) so I build a Dataset class

```
class Dataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self,data_root):
        self.letters=[]
        self.labels=[]
        labels=0

        for lan in os.listdir(data_root):
            lan_folder = os.path.join(data_root,lan)
            labels=labels+1
            for type in os.listdir(lan_folder):
                type_folder = os.path.join(lan_folder,type)

                for name in os.listdir(type_folder):
                    file_names=os.path.join(type_folder,name)
                    phonegrams=open(file_names,encoding='utf-8').read().strip().split('\n')
                    self.letters.append(phonegrams)
                    self.labels.append(labels)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.letters[index],self.labels[index]



dataset=Dataset(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\David\Programas\Sequence to tag 1st version\phon\training')
```

when I print the first item of dataset I get:

```
([['ij jA: A:z zy yi i']], [1])
```

My problem is I want to tokenize and index each file , because these files have little words inside, so I made this:

```
tokenize = lambda x: x.split()
LANS = Field(tokenize=tokenize,init_token='<sos>',eos_token='<eos>',sequential=True)
LANS.build_vocab(dataset)
```

and then :

```
LANS.vocab.freqs.most_common(1)
```

and I get

```
[('ij jA: A:z zy ,1)]
```

is using the complete sentence and not each word, is supposed to get me something like:

ij : 1

ja: 2